Path without using __file__
Executing python script ( my.py ) in Spyder
Script ( my.py ) is placed in folder D:\X\Z
Need to get path of script from within the script, ie D:\X\Z
__file__ doesn't work for Spyder
Other solutions from stackoverflow threads returns various paths like C:\Users\ABCD etc
Several posts in the forum with similar questions, but couldn't find any solution.
